# Args and Kwargs, but for function outputs (not just inputs)

Tags: python, function, arguments, keyword-argument

I love the functionality of *a and **kw for arbitrarily sized inputs into functions but I was wondering if there was a similar pythonic way to return an arbitrary amount of outputs? It is of course possible to return all functional outputs within a list or a dictionary and have that be more portable and a prespecified number of outputs, but defining a list and a dictionary to return outputs could get cumbersome and not always be useful. Is there a cleaner way to return an arbitrary amount of outputs that this:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs)
    a, b, c, d, one, two = do_stuff(*args, **kwargs)
    return [one, two] {'a' = a, 'b' = b, 'c' = c, 'd' = d}

output_list, output_dict = foo(args, kwargs)
bar = output_dict['b']
```

Comment: You need a comma between the list and dictionary in the `return` statement.

Comment: You can do this, but return values tend not to be as complex as parameters. If you need to do this, you should probably be using class instances.

Comment: You aren't returning arbitrary output; if you were, you could simply write `return do_stuff(*args, **kwargs)`. You are *constructing* a rather particular output value from the return values of `do_stuff`.

Comment: @Barmar that's a great point, instances would be better adapt to this thank you!